# -[CCSprite setPosition:]: message sent to deallocated instance, what now?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I´ve been having some problems with a bug that causes my game to crash. First it just gave me a "BAD_ACCESS" but by enabling Zombie objects the debugger said this:

**-[CCSprite setPosition:]: message sent to deallocated instance xxxx**

The crash happens when object A and B collides, but ONLY if the collision takes place at the same moment as object B is created.

Both A and B should be destroyed at collision, this works just fine except in the situation described above. I´m using Box2D for what it´s worth.

Is there any way to track the error in a more specific way? Like if it´s A or B that´s giving me trouble.

Comment: some code would help :) eg how the sprites are created, added/removed from some parent, do you add them to arrays for some purpose, etc ...

Comment: Keep in mind that you can't remove Box2D objects while they're colliding. Perhaps that's part of the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the simulator, enable MallocStackLogging and NSDebugEnabled.  Then when you get this message, make note of the process id and memory address of the offending object. Then in your terminal, use `malloc_history <pid> <memory_address>` to see the history of allocs and deallocs of this address.  It will give you a stack trace of each alloc and dealloc.  The most recent alloc is probably the place where you've allocated something that you possibly didn't retain, or the most recent dealloc is the place where you dealloc'd it accidentally.

Heres the man page for malloc_history:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/malloc_history.1.html